# ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object' Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, observable

What i do wrong? It's work but i got this error on my console.

My Model:

```
export class Form {
  id: number;
  formTaxID: number;
  name: string;
  formYear: number;
  sectionID: number;
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

My Service:

```
  public getAllForms(): Observable<Form> {
    return this._network.get(this.baseUrl, GlobalAPI.endpoints.forms.base).
      pipe(map(response => (response.data.forms)));
  }
```

form.facade.ts:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FormsFacade {
  forms$: BehaviorSubject<Form> = new BehaviorSubject(new Form());

  // Lifecycle
  constructor(private _formsAPI: FormsApi, private _router: Router) {
  }

  // Methods
  getAllForms() {
    this._formsAPI.getAllForms()
    .subscribe(forms => {
      this.forms$.next(forms);
    });
  }
}
```

components ts:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  forms$ = this._formsFacade.forms$;

  constructor(private _formsFacade: FormsFacade) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._formsFacade.getAllForms();
  }

}
```

template:

```
    <div class="table-container" *ngIf="forms$ | async as forms">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">a</th>
            <th scope="col">b</th>
            <th scope="col">c/th>
            <th scope="col">d</th>
            <th scope="col">e</th>
            <th scope="col">f</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let form of forms">
            <tr>
            <td>{{form.formTaxID}}</td>
            <a [routerLink]="['edit-form/', form.id]">
              {{ form.name }}</a>
            <td>{{form.formYear}}</td>
            <td>{{form.sectionID}}</td>
            <td>{{form.createdAt | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy בשעה hh:mm '}}</td>
            <td>{{form.updatedAt | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy בשעה hh:mm '}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its work but i got this error on my console.

I try to change to

```
  public getAllForms(): Observable<Form[]> {
    return this._network.get(this.baseUrl, GlobalAPI.endpoints.forms.base).
      pipe(map(response => (response.data.forms)));
  }
```

But i got this error on my facade

```
rgument of type 'Form[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Form'.
  Type 'Form[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Form': id, formTaxID, name, formYear, sectionIDts(2345)
```

The problem is the "ng for" not recognize it as a array of object.
How can i Fix this error on my console ?

Comment: change `public getAllForms(): Observable<Form>` to `public getAllForms(): Observable<Form[]>`

Comment: I'd say change your behaviourSubject: forms$: BehaviorSubject<Form> = new BehaviorSubject(new Form()); -> forms$: BehaviorSubject<Form[]> = new BehaviorSubject([new Form()]);

Answer (score 0):

The problem in Facade can be corrected as:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FormsFacade {
  forms$: BehaviorSubject<Form> = new BehaviorSubject(new Form());

  // Lifecycle
  constructor(private _formsAPI: FormsApi, private _router: Router) {
  }

  // Methods
  getAllForms() {
    this._formsAPI.getAllForms()
    .subscribe(forms => {
      forms.forEach((form)=>{
          this.forms$.next(form);
      });

    });
  }
}
```

Because forms$ variable is a BehaviorSubject with single Form.

Comment: Ok, so what is the solution ?

Comment: I corrected the problem in Facade, let me know the location/line number etc. of other problems. I'll try to resolve them as well

Comment: with your solution now the data not show on the ui. ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.